# C++ Switch loop error

Tags: c++, switch-statement

I'm a C++ beginner. My problem is, if the user accidentally inputs a letter, the program will send the error message and it wont loop back. This is my code:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int q;
    A:
    cout << "[1] Name";
    cout << "\n[2] Address";
    cout << "\nEnter your choice: ";
    cin >> q;

    switch (q)
    {
    case 1:
        cout << "XXXXXXXXXX" << endl;
        break;
    case 2:
        cout << "XXXXXXXXXX" << endl;
        break;
    default:
        cout << "Error! Enter only numbers from 1 - 2" << endl;
        goto A;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output was :

```
[1] Name
[2] Address
Enter your choice: x
Error! Enter only numbers from 1 - 2
[1] Name
[2] Address
Enter your choice: Error! Enter only numbers from 1 - 2
[1] Name
[2] Address
Enter your choice: Error! Enter only numbers from 1 - 2
...
```

It should be like this,

```
[1] Name
[2] Address
Enter your choice: 8
Error! Enter only numbers from 1 - 2

[1] Name
[2] Address
Enter your choice:
```

If user enters a wrong number, it loops back, and if the user enters a letter, it should loop back like this too.
What is wrong?

Comment: Why should it loop back?  You never made a loop.  If you want to to loop back to get good input you will need to code that behavior into the program.

Comment: Note that you are missing the `break;` instruction a the end of each `case`. This will cause the program to continue executing following `case`

Comment: So *add* a loop? You do know of the four types of loops available in C++?

Comment: I tried to add a loop but it gets me into an endless loop :(

Comment: loop need a condition to quit

Comment: @JérômeLeducq oops. my bad.

Comment: Also, depending on which C++ standard is used by your compiler, you will have *undefined behavior* as `q` can be uninitialized. You need another way to check for non-numeric input than the `default` case, and only go on to the `switch` statement once you know you have numeric input.

Comment: And please show us the attempt you made with the loop, and we cann help you find out what the problem with it is.

Comment: Please show some examples of expected output for a given input...and please don't do this by adding a comment but by editing your question.

Comment: There, got it edited.

Comment: No, no, nope, nope. Do not use `goto` when you have a structured looping construct in the language itself.

Comment: +1 for @StoryTeller.  In fact, generally avoid `goto` other than for jumping to an error handler.  And for that, try using `try...catch` instead.

Comment: @CodeswithHammer, an even better idiom would be RAII.

Comment: @StoryTeller: I'm not familiar with RAII.  Looks like I should learn it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that when you enter a non-integer input, the input is not actually extracted from the input-buffer, so each iteration of the loop you will attempt to read the same input over and over again.

What you need to do is rely on the fact that illegal input (non-integer in your case) will cause the stream to set its `failbit`, that the input operator `>>` function returns a reference to the stream, and that the state of a stream can be checked in a simple [boolean condition](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool).

Something like

```
if (std::cin >> q)
{
    // Successfully read an integer
}
else
{
    // Failed to read an integer, input is probably something else

    // Clear the failbit
    std::cin.clear();

    // Explicitly ignore the rest of the line
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');

    // Output error message
}
```

The above code can be put in a loop that is exited by setting a boolean variable in the switch-cases for valid integers.

---

References:

- [`std::ios::clear`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear)
- [`std::istream::ignore`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore).
- [`std::numeric_limits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits)

Comment: Huh.  I hadn't thought of putting the `cin` directly into the `if` or `do` condition.  Nice thinking!

Answer (score -1):

Since the input might not be numeric, let's allow for that.  I'm assuming the use of `System.String` -- if it isn't, modifying this snippet is left as an exercise for the student.

```
using System;

String entry = "";
int entry_val = 0;
bool valid = false;

do
{
    //menu goes here

    cin >> entry;
    if ( entry >= "1" && entry <= "2" )
    {
        entry_val = entry.ToInt();
        valid = true;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Error! Enter only numbers from 1 - 2" << endl;
    }
while (valid == false)
```

...

continue with the `switch() {}` block.

Comment: So your custom made String class should have operator<= and operator >= too... To read a number from stdin?

Comment: @NathanOliver: How so?  Should I clear `entry` on error?  The original question wanted the entry loop to continue until they got valid input.

Comment: @Bob__: I seem to recall that `System.String` includes those operators.

Comment: @CodeswithHammer My bad.  entry is some type of string.  If you are going to suggest this to the OP you should include a complete working example.  There is no way for the OP to use this answer without whatever `String` is.

Comment: @CodeswithHammer System.String is not C++ it is C++CLI which this question is not tagged with.

Comment: @NathanOliver and @StoryTeller:  I'll edit my answer to explicitly identify `System.String`.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Oops.  I deserve my -1 score for that oversight.

Comment: I'm a bit rusty (at best) with c++/cli, but I thougt that System.String was for c#, shouldn't it be System::String for C++?

Comment: You're probably right, @Bob__.  I haven't used raw C++ in quite some time, so I'm a bit rusty with that.